# How to calculate product weight in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I want to calculate total product weight in odoo quotations and sale orders, but i don't know that how to write the method for it, can someone give me hint about it? [image: here is in image total weight written in bottom]

```
class ProductWeight(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

    th_weight = fields.Float('Weight')

    @api.one
    def _calcweight(self):
        currentweight = 0
        for weight in self.weight_ids:
            currentweight = currentweight + weight.th_weight
        self.weight_total = currentweight

    weight_total = fields.Float('Total Weight', store=True, compute="_calcweight")
```

here is my method for calculating total weight above, but its not right, give me 404 errors.

Comment: it gives me 404 not found error

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] of the problem? 404 means something very specific, so you seem to be using an API incorrectly

Comment: this is my full code, i think i am doing mistake at some point which i don't understand

Comment: ok let me edit the question

Comment: That can't be all the code. How does python know how to connect to the server?

Comment: i am new one on odoo, don't know how python connect to server, can you help me out please

Comment: I don't know odoo at all, that is why I asked. Somehow, you are connecting Python to odoo and hitting a 404, which is a networking error, which means there is a configuration setting that is incorrect.

Comment: no its not configuration setting, its method problem somewhere, i connected python through vagrant

Comment: You just lost me... vagrant manages virtual machines. Python has no part of that. The Odoo API from Python **needs** to know to communicate with the server. There has to be some part of the code that you tell it the address of the server.

Comment: sorry i didn't know that

Comment: It's okay. Just, there's a lot of parts here that you need to manage. I have been reading over the [installation guide](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html) and it does discuss a configuration file

Comment: i have done it, working for me now

Comment: Glad to hear. Sorry for being difficult :) You're welcome to answer your own question below with your steps in case others find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I suggest using the following code

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class ProductWeight(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'sale.order.line'
   th_weight = fields.Float(string='Weight',
                               store=True,
                               related='product_id.weight')

class ProductWeightOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    @api.depends('order_line.th_weight')
    def _calcweight(self):
        currentweight = 0
        for order_line in self.order_line:
            currentweight = currentweight + order_line.th_weight
        self.weight_total = currentweight

    weight_total = fields.Float(compute='_calcweight', string='Total Weight')
```

you must set the parameter weight in the product master data in any case you can modify the th_weight field so that it is not related to the product, a user would have to fill this information